# SWRevealViewController with NavigationController - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to make an app in which my navigation bar appears on all pages. When I click on any row of side menu(done through `SWRevealViewController`), I want the page that opens to have a navigation bar on top. In the image below, I want the same navigation bar as the HomeViewController on the page that has "Menu" label. How can I do this? Please help. I am new to iOS. I am doing this in Xcode 8 and Swift 3.
[image: Here is the image]

EDIT : I want something like this: [image] I have placed the side menu button on the reveal view controller. I can see it on the front view controller at runtime but how to connect the target and action of revealviewcontroller then, so that the side menu opens? If this is done then my problem of navigation controller on "Menu" label page will be solved automatically

Comment: Root View controller of your SlideBar Must be Kept inside UINavigation controller.

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: Put NavigationController -> RevealController -> front(Home controller) -> Rear(SideMenuController)

Comment: @Amanpreet please check edited question

Comment: @Dia please check answer. May be you want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose outlet of menu is btn_Menu. In controller's view did load I set bar button's action and target programmatically.

```
 btn_Menu.target = self.revealViewController()
 btn_Menu.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
```

Have a look at this image structure that you need. Sorry not very clear but perhaps solve your issue:

[image]

Comment: My question is where do I create outlet of that button? As that controller's class is set to SWRevealViewController

Comment: Put button on home view controller. Make outlet here in home.

Comment: I have done that in my initial question but it isn't fulfilling the purpose of getting the navigation bar on the "Menu" label page

Comment: RevealController is just use to set the rear and front. Here we take rear as sidemenu and front is home.When you run the app you will see home because we set it as front of reveal.. Did you check http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Comment: Yes that's working. I am just worried about the navigation bar. How to do that?

Comment: Follow your edited part of question just put button on home. That mean your initial controller should be navigation controller then you can see navigation bar on each controller that are connected with it.

Comment: There is no navigation bar on frontViewController so how do I add menu bar button there?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check the image . NC - Navigation controller

Comment: In this case there will be different navigation controllers for front and rear flow of app, whereas I am looking for a solution by which I can use the same navigation bar throughout the app

Comment: You can use only one for home this was my requirement that I shared. But its good to use proper Navigation as you can check on Appcoda tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Amanpreet! It works as in the image, except that my initial view controller is set to the reveal view controller ,i.e, I didn't use the first navigation controller. But it works exactly as required :)

Comment: Good to listen that it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the starting points of your `ViewControllers` in a `NavigationController` of their own so in this case you need to embed the `ViewController` which has the menu label in a `NavigationController` and make the side menu segue to the `NavigationController` not the `ViewController`

hope my answer helps you

Comment: please check edited question. I want same navigation bar on home view controller as well as the view controller having "Menu" label

Comment: you could make a subclass from a uiviewcontroller 'BaseViewController' and in it's viewDidLoad make it add the buttons to the navigationBar programmatically and all the viewcontrollers you will show from the menu inherit from 'BaseViewController' and embed them in a navigationController

Comment: i will add a new answer with details for you now

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `Navigation Controller` for sabe bar Controller
Follow the steps :

Select side bar `viewcontroller > go to Editior menu > Embed in > Click Navigation Controller`

Comment: please check edited question. I want same navigation bar on home view controller as well as the view controller having "Menu" label

Comment: You want to use same manu navigation bar with "Menu" title for Side bar?

Comment: yes i want same navigation bar on "Menu" title page and HomeViewController

Answer (score 0):

1) create a new ViewController Class called 'BaseViewController'

2)  in the BaseViewController viewDidLoad add the following code and change the images names and targets also add the left button for the menu

```
  let btn1 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
    btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.Methodname), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn1)

    let btn2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
    btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
    btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
    btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.MethodName), for: .touchUpInside)
    let item2 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btn2)  

    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1,item2], animated: true)
```

3) make the viewControllers which you will show from the side menu like the one with menu label inherits from BaseViewController and in it's viewDidLoad make it call         super.viewDidLoad()

4) embed the viewControllers which you will show from the side menu in a navigationController

Answer (score 0):

Using `Container View` may help.

Replace the UIView in the middle (Content) with a Container View and that container can be a `UINavigationController`. And to avoid having **2 NavigationBars** you can hide the NavigationBar of the ContainerView.

The blue highlighted view is the `ContainerView` inside the **Controller** that is implementing SideMenu

[image]